Wall of Force: how you can entrap moving creatures?
RAW there is no saving throw for the 5th level spell
Wall of Force.
My question is:
Can this spell entrap creatures when they are moving
in the sky/on the ground/in the water?
IMVHO the rule spells do what they say they do in this case (intentionally?) leave a lot to DM discretion.

I don't see what gets left to the DM's discretion. I guess you can come up with some weird cases where some ruling needs to be made. However, I don't see it for the general case of casting this spell. What exactly is not clear from the spell description and would require a DM to figure out? What is the scenario you picture the questions arising in?

As VLAZ mentions, yea, the question to you is: why not?



a flying enemy is diving towards the characters and gets trapped: the DM has to decide the injuries caused by crushing against the Wall of Force.


any creature that breathes the oxygen dissolved in water. and swims near the surface of the sea can be trapped in a sphere almost entirely above the water (so almost without water) for 10 minutes: the DM has to decide if the creature is injured/killed by suffocation


in a skirmish, an horizontal Wall of Force is cast ~1.5/2 feet above the ground and  only the enemies are trapped below it: how fast do they crawl out of it?




is a special circumstance. Also not one that normally happens. The times you have to consider the creature's movement as you're casting the spell is close to zero. I suppose only if you try to do something like a readied action and even then that usually resolves before/after movement. Not during. So, what you're trying to ask is an extremely specific circumstance you've not even described in the question. Because I really can't think when you'd have to consider creature moving + it hitting a wall. Moreover, it's even trivial to make a ruling, so it hardly does "leave a lot to the DM"



is, like, hardly an issue? It'd definitely not specific to Wall of Force. You can have the same situation with a rope. And you pull a fish (or whatever aquatic creature) on land. 3) is another extremely specific and an almost trivial matter. Overall, you've put up few edge cases and claimed the spell is underspecified. When it's hardly the spell's fault, nor really such a burden to the DM, IMO.


Hitting a wall of force at high velocity can easily happen, because the wall is invisible, and so the opponents do not know it is there and will run full speed into it. We had that exact situation happen, when we were pursued by a hellfire engine with a dozen hobgoblins riding along. We cast a WoF in the way, and had them all crash into it, full bore. Howerver there are no rules for assigning damage in such a case, the DM had to come up with something for it. But this would be a different question.

Yes, you can trap moving creatures
The way the 5e rules treat movement in combat, at the point in time when a spell effect resolves, a target creature has a specific, defined location1. As you can select where the spell effect resolves, you can pick that location to entrap moving creatures, without a saving throw. That, together with the fact that it is hard to get out of, is what makes wall of force so powerful.
This also works on flying creatures, as the spell says, it can be free floating, so you can target any area in the air:

It can be free floating or resting on a solid surface.

And it works on swimming creatures, as you can cast it into water.
So it does not matter for this if the creatures are walking, flying or swimming or how high their speed is, as long as you can target the area with your spell. This has nothing to do with DM discretion; of course a DM could overrule the rules as they always can, but according to the rules, this just works.
Burrowing creatures
The only exception would be burrowing creatures. The wall of force "springs into existence at a point you choose", and the spell area rules say (PH 204):

A spell’s effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin. If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a location within the area of effect, that location isn’t included in the spell’s area.

So even if you chose the globe form of the wall, the globe would not actually extend into the ground or the walls, as there is no unblocked line, so areas below ground or in the walls are not included in the spell's area. That means, a burrowing creature could escape into the ground and get around the wall that way. One way to try and avoid this could be to target the globe above ground, so that it just closes underneath the creature or pushes it up into the globe. The spell says:

If the wall cuts through a creature's space when it appears, the creature is pushed to one side of the wall (your choice which side).

This works well to isolate creatures from walls. However, vertical space is not really well defined in the rules, which mostly treat space in combat as a flat, two-dimentional affair. So while I think this should work also for the ground, you should check with your DM on how they handle this corner case.

1 Combat is turn based, and by the game mechanics creatures normally only move on their turn, unless they have a Ready action to move on a trigger condition. That means, when you cast the spell on your turn, it is not the turn of the other creature, so its position is known. Even if it had a reaction trigger to move away if you start casting a spell, normally the reaction only happens after the trigger, and they would be cought; moreover, even if your DM allowed it to move before you are done casting -- say, reacting to you starting to cast, you likely only chose the spells target as it resolves, so you could just pick the area they moved to. Lastly, even if you cast wall of force as a reaction on their turn, in response to them moving, or starting to move, the same applies: at the time when your spell resolves they either have not yet moved, or have moved, and you can select their space as your target. 
